# Loop to match both URLs that go to the same page

Tags: javascript, html, loops

On my website both the following URLs go to the same page:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhaERteVA4cmJwdDg/                     Site URL
https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhaERteVA4cmJwdDg/index.html      Index page URL

I have a loop to highlight the current page link in the navigation menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        li {
            display: inline;
        }
        a.current {
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhaERteVA4cmJwdDg/index.html">Index</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhaERteVA4cmJwdDg/news.html">News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhaERteVA4cmJwdDg/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhaERteVA4cmJwdDg/about.html">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <script>
        for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
            if (document.links[i].href == document.URL) {
                document.links[i].className = 'current';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now the problem is it doesn't highlight the *Index* link when you go to the main site URL:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhaERteVA4cmJwdDg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    if (document.links[i].href == document.URL || document.links[i].href == document.URL + 'index.html') {
        document.links[i].className = 'current';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test whether the current URL ends in ".html" and if not add "index.html" before the for loop:

```
    var currentURL = document.URL;
    if (currentURL.slice(-5) != ".html") {
        currentURL = currentURL.replace(/\/?$/,"/index.html");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
        if (document.links[i].href === currentURL) {
            document.links[i].className = 'current';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I just came up with a simpler approach.